# Generating Logs from multiple directories in Logstash. Logs not appearing in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to collect logs from multiple directories through Logstash and send them to Elasticsearch.

This is my configuration:

```
input{
        file {
                path => ["/XXX/XXX/results/**/log_file.txt"]
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
         }
}
filter {
         grok {
                pattern_definitions => { "THREAD_NAME" => "%{WORD}?%{NUMBER}?" }
                match => { "message" => "%{SPACE}?%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:asctime}?%{SPACE}?\|%{SPACE}?%{THREAD_NAME:thread_name}"}
    }
}


output{
         elasticsearch {
                 hosts => ["x.x.x.x:9200"]
        }
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

The file path is a relative path.

The logs are placed inside different directories placed inside the results directory:
results/dir/log_file.txt.

I have tried this configuration with stdin and logs appeared inside Kibana, but Logstash doesn't pick up the logs in the directories. Please advise.

Comment: You cannot use a relative path in a file input. It should be logging an error. What do you see in the logstash logs?

Comment: As Badger stated the location should be as seen from the root, (which is the / ) just go to the directory and type pwd to find the full path of it :)

Comment: you guys were correct! thank you! changing the path to ["/home/user/XXX/XXX/results/**/log_file.txt"] fixed it. Apparently, it could not find the path before that.